# In Sitecore 7.1 when I try to open the media library browser to insert an image a popup says the item was deleted

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-media-library, sitecore7.1

I have a simple template inheriting from `Standard Template` with an `Image` field. After creating a new item, when I go to add content and click on the field's toolbar item `Open Media Library` I get a message telling me `The selected item could not be found.` and suggesting that another use deleted it.

I am the only user on the installation, and the item is definitely there. I have done a few other Sitecore installs to make sure it's not just a corrupt project, and I've checked the logs to no avail.

I'm using Sitecore 7.1 rev. 130926 (the latest version as of this writing). I've done extensive searching and can't find anybody reporting a similar issue - my guess is it's a simple configuration (botched ID or path?), but I can't seem to locate it by scanning the configs for relevant keywords.

There are other issues with using the `Browse` editor, but I believe this is related to the missing Media Library item. The `File Selector` and other reasonably equivalent editors do not fail so I don't think it's a browser configuration. I've tried on Chrome, IE and Firefox and all respond the same way.

Any suggestions on further courses of action would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the template path in content editor tree and the image xpath configured to identify what is wrong .. Code and screen shot will help.

Comment: Appreciate the input, but I didn't post any code snippets because everything obvious was checking out. I was looking more for a "have you tried checking config x" type of answer because I had run out of places to look for problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error, following are the step i have done to resolve.
1) I upload all my Images in the Media image folder 
2) I have publish this folder.
3) Clicked on the Browse Button-> My Images
4) On Right hand side you will find the Tree view Icon above the Search Box 
5) Click on it will see the Media Library with Tree consisting of all the Images.
6) Select the Image from that.
7) After this image get displayed in Image box,
8) Now click on Open Media Library Box and it will not give the error.

Answer (score 0):

On your 'simple template' check the standard value for your `Image` field on your data template. It may be that it is pointing to a path which does not exist in your media library.

Comment: Thanks, but the standard values were all as expected. The way the errors were appearing it seemed like the entire media library was just not being properly processed, and it was seemingly due to the xml definitions were mangled. Just weird.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, but it took an install on a completely separate machine and a comparison of the entire folder/file structure. There are two Sitecore XMLs that get written to the bin folder: `Sitecore.Client.XML` and `Sitecore.Kernel.xml` - both contain Sitecore assembly definitions, but the ones on my machine were not being generated properly. Once I copied the files over to my local install everything started working as expected.

So, the short answer is: a corrupted installation.

I frankly have no idea why the files would differ from my machine to another - once this project is finished, I'll have to do some research and report back. I have several Sitecore versions installed, and it could be a conflict between versions or dependencies? If I find anything, I'll make notes here.